# table selection query giving alias in mysql

Tags: mysql, alias

Hi am having a query in mysql as follows `show tables like 'stud%'`, Suppose i want to give an alias over that how can it be done.

I tried the following

`show tables like 'stud%' as stud_tables`. Its not working.

Is it possible..?am not sure..Anyway i just need to give a column name as part of the list am getting when i execute the first query.. `show tables like 'stud%'`

Comment: Looking at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html it is invalid syntax. What do you want to exactly do? Rename tables? Create views?

Comment: i just want to have a column name of my own for the list am getting when i execute show tables like 'stud%'..dats all

Comment: Which language you are using?

Comment: `SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES as stud_tables where table_name like 'stud%'`;
:-)

Comment: If you let us know the reason why you are seeking this, someone might have provided a better solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could try the more complex way using the [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA` database][1]:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d110/6

```
SELECT t.TABLE_NAME AS stud_tables
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS t
WHERE  t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' -- exclude system tables
  AND  t.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_0d110' -- database name
  AND  t.TABLE_NAME LIKE 'stud%'   -- table name
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tables-table.html

Comment: but in this case it will show the tables from all tables..right.?

Comment: can i do smthng to limit that to tables under a particular database.?

Comment: `SELECT t.TABLE_NAME AS stud_tables
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS t
WHERE  t.TABLE_SCHEMA = '%databasename%'
  AND  t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
  AND  t.TABLE_NAME LIKE 'stud%'
`

Comment: @TijoKVarghese Why did you ask this question if you didn't even open your database and check to see **what** columns the TABLES table has in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA database?