# MySQL, SHOW TABLES LIKE "somePrefix%", change column name result

Tags: mysql

I am using `SHOW TABLES LIKE` syntax to print table names in current DB which start with certain prefix.

I am interested that the result column name will be configurable by me (e.g. when you do a select you can name certain field `AS` different name: `SELECT x AS y FROM z`.

Is it possible to do the same while using the `SHOW TABLES` syntax?

i am aware of the option to query the information_schema using `SELECT`, but i do not wish to grant this option to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a view based on information_schema [1] for your user and adjust permissions accordingly. All answers to similar questions point to information schema [2,3].

[1] http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/views.html

[2] [table selection query giving alias in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11204462/table-selection-query-giving-alias-in-mysql)

[3] [Alias to Show Tables MySQL Result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11378375/alias-to-show-tables-mysql-result)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='your_schema_name' 
AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'somePrefix%'
```